# Make select box for Integer value

Tags: symfony

This code makes the normal form for integer.

```
  $form = $this->createFormBuilder($row)
        ->add('inputnumber',null,array('label' => 'please input number',
            'data' => '3'))
```

However I would like to make select box like below for the integer value.

```
<select name=inputnumber>
<option value=1>
<option value=2>
<option value=3 selected>
</select>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [choice](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/reference/forms/types/choice.html) field.

```
->add('inputnumber', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(1, 2, 3)
))
```