# Making select box for Integer value form mapper

Tags: symfony

According this article.

[Make select box for Integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892888/make-select-box-for-integer-value)

I made this code

```
$formMapper
->add('length','choice',array('choices' => array(30,60,90,120)))
```

But when I choose '90' ,'2' is recorded in Database.

I want to choose '90' and record in Database '90' as integer.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$formMapper->add('length','choice',array('choices' => array(30 => 30, 60 => 60, 90 => 90, 120 => 120)))
```

From the Symfony book, [Choice Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices):

> The choices option is an array, where the array key is the item value
>   and the array value is the item's label